# Can't connect to certain sites

Tags: networking

I've been having an odd issue for months (8-12?) now, and I'm out of ideas. I own a site, hosted by GoDaddy, that I can't connect to only from my Ubuntu laptops. I have two (Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS and Ubuntu 13.10) laptops, and I can't connect to the site using Chrome, FF, or even wget. Windows machines, iOS devices, and even Raspberry Pis can access it just fine. Wired or wireless makes no difference. This seems to be a port 80 issue, as I **can** ssh into the host from my Ubuntu laptops. I can connect to the site on the laptops when connected via my work VPN.

I figured a Pi (running Raspbian) would make a good comparison, so here are some of the things I've done, comparing the laptops to the Pi:

`traceroute` is identical (times out after hop 14, i.e., `* * *` for lines 15 - 30). Last hop is to be38.trmc0215-01.ars.mgmt.phx3.gdg (184.168.0.69)

`ping` is identically successful

`wget` on the laptops eventually just eventually gives me "failed: Connection timed out." The Pi retrieves the page normally.

I noticed that the laptops had 127.0.0.1 as the nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`, whereas the Pi had my router (192.168.1.1). I turned off dnsmasq on one of the laptops, rebooted, and now it also shows 192.168.1.1, but no effect. (Should I turn it back on?)

The site is not referenced in any of the `/etc/hosts` files.

`telnet`ing to port 80 succeeds immediately on the Pi, but on the laptops it times out ("telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out")

Other possibly relevant info:

My router is running dd-wrt. ISP is Time Warner.

```
pi@pi1 -bash ~
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian

joe@joe-linlaptop bash ~
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.3 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 

joe@inspiron -bash ~
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="13.10, Saucy Salamander"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 13.10"
VERSION_ID="13.10"
```

Valid subdomains show the same symptoms as www (timing out). Invalid domains fail immediately.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Let me know what other information I should post, as I'm sure I've left some important details out ☺

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following nameservers: `8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4`
They are hosted by Google.

Open your connection settings, and apply these changes to all connections you use:

1. Select the connection and click *Edit...*
2. Go to IPv4 tab and change *method* from *Automatic (DHCP)* to *Automatic (DHCP), Addresses only*
3. Enter the both nameservers into *DNS Server*. Copy them as they are with comma.
4. Perform the same at the IPv6 tab
5. Save and try to access your website.

Comment: No dice, thanks for the suggestion. I actually had already tried this, but forgot to mention it. I tried it again anyways, just in case, though.

Answer (score 0):

What I would try after all what you already did:

- Lowering the MTU.
- Dump the traffic on a working and in a non working system, then compare the results in Wireshark.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

Lowering the MTU didn't make any difference.

I'm not very familiar with Wireshark. Here's what I did:
On an Ubuntu system and on the Pi, I ran:
sudo tcpdump -niwlan0 -s0 -w/tmp/dump_no_work.pcap port 80 or icmp

Comment: Sorry, I'm not loving this commenting system. 

I looked at the output in Wireshark, but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for. On the system that didn't work, it sent the first line "...http [SYN]...", then would repeat it after a delay. On the Pi, it only sent that line once, and then received something back. Is there something in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: @pepik "http" in this case just means port 80. the [SYN] is the TCP SYN packet from the TCP handshake. When the server receives the SYN packet it should reply with a SYN-ACK packet, and the the client replies with an ACK. So your client is not even receiving back the SYN-ACK packet from the server, that means, that the connection is broken at the very start.

Comment: @pepik Does the SYN packets sent by your clients have a difference?

Comment: @pepik Based on your info from the dump I think you maybe have [this](http://serverfault.com/q/235965/203306) problem.

Comment: So when I checked on things this morning, both laptops are connecting, though I didn't change anything between last night and this morning. Grrr. I expect that it'll only work temporarily. Thanks to everyone who's made suggestions so far, I will update this thread if / when I need to revisit this issue. Next thing I'm going to try is @falconer's suggestion about disabling the tcp window scaling.